# Writing a string to file as a byte in Java

Tags: java

I'm having a little trouble writing the values I want to a file.
I'm using RandomAccessFile to output the values. What I want to do is take a string (which contains two digits, 0-9) and write them to a file as a byte.
I've tried a few different ways but cannot seem to nail it..
Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by _as a byte_?

Comment: Two 0-F values. Although I will only be using 0-9 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String yourString = "0F"; 
 byte aByte = Byte.parseByte(yourString, 16);
```

And then just write that byte in your file and you are all set.

**NOTE:** 
That 16 is the radix, use 10 for decimal, 16 for hex

Comment: @resetter no problem, if this solves your problem mark the question as resolved and that's it.